# how to pass data from listview to another activity page?

Tags: java, android, listview

newbie question here. so im trying to pass title from 1stPage listview to 2ndPage EditText which means if i click on Title1 on 1stPage,  2ndPage editText will display Title1 also. ive learnt about putting extra in intent but i do not know how to take data from listview. tqvm in advanced.

1.MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

ListView l1;
String[] t1={"TITLE 1","TITLE 2"};
String[] d1={"Detail 1","Detail 2"};
String[] s1={"Content 1", "Content 2"};

TextView textView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);

    l1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    l1.setAdapter(new dataListAdapter(t1, d1, s1));


}

class dataListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    String[] Title, Detail, Content;

    dataListAdapter() {
        Title = null;
        Detail = null;
        Content=null;
    }

    public dataListAdapter(String[] text, String[] text1, String[] text3) {
        Title = text;
        Detail = text1;
        Content = text3;

    }

    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return Title.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View row;
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom, parent, false);
        final TextView title, detail, detail2;
        title = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.title);
        detail = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.detail);
        detail2 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.detail2);
        title.setText(Title[position]);
        detail.setText(Detail[position]);
        detail2.setText(Content[position]);

        l1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                String selected = title.getText().toString();
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main2Activity.class);
                i.putExtra("name", selected);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        return (row);
    }

}


}
```

2.Main2Activity.java

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
EditText editText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et);

    Intent in = getIntent();
    String name = in.getStringExtra(("name"));
    editText.setText(name);
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare this method in `MainActivity` after the lines

```
    l1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    l1.setAdapter(new dataListAdapter(t1, d1, s1));

    l1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            String selected = t1[position];
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main2Activity.class);
            i.putExtra("name", selected);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

and remove from `dataListAdapter` class

in another activity, get the title using following method

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String name = extras.getString("name");
editText.setText(name);
```

Hope it'll work.

Comment: oo. ive tried it. 1st, i use String selected = title.getText().toString() but since "title" is declared in getView() method, i cant access it.

Comment: then i tried to declare textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title); and use String selected = textView.getText().toString() but this doesnt work either. Maybe im not understanding the basic concept since im still new in android.

Comment: can you help me for my new question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35580744/how-to-verify-email-when-uploading-image-to-database/35581380?noredirect=1#comment58851025_35581380

Answer (score 0):

In first activity you should put extra argument to intent like this. It's also good to store "argument" String in MainActivity as constant and always refer to it in other places.

```
public static final String ARG_FROM_MAIN = "argument";
```

// I assume B.class is your second ativity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, B.class); 
intent.putExtra("argument", "Title1");
startActivity(intent);
```

Then in **B** activity you retrieve argument like this:

```
String passedArg = getIntent().getExtras().getString("argument");
enteredValue.setText(passedArg);
```