# How to verify email when uploading image to database

Tags: java, android

newbie question here, so im uploading image in the form of blob which i follows a tutorial. my problem right now is i want to upload my image on specific email which means i put in the email and the image will be uploaded to that specific email in the database. ive done the uploading image part but have no idea how to put the email. tqvm in advanced.

1.MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

public static final String UPLOAD_URL = "http://10.0.3.2/AndroidImageBlob/upload.php";
public static final String UPLOAD_KEY = "image";
public static final String TAG = "MY MESSAGE";

private int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;

private Button buttonChoose;
private Button buttonUpload;

private EditText editTextId;

private ImageView imageView;

private Bitmap bitmap;

private Uri filePath;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    editTextId = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextId);

    buttonChoose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonChoose);
    buttonUpload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUpload);

    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    buttonChoose.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonUpload.setOnClickListener(this);
}

private void showFileChooser() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

        filePath = data.getData();
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp){
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return encodedImage;
}

private void uploadImage(){

    class UploadImage extends AsyncTask<Bitmap,Void,String> {

        ProgressDialog loading;
        RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loading = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Uploading Image", "Please wait...", true, true);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            loading.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Bitmap...params) {
            Bitmap bitmap = params[0];
            String uploadImage = getStringImage(bitmap);

            HashMap<String,String> data = new HashMap<>();
            data.put(UPLOAD_KEY, uploadImage);

            String result = rh.sendPostRequest(UPLOAD_URL,data);

            return result;
        }


    }

    UploadImage ui = new UploadImage();
    ui.execute(bitmap);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == buttonChoose) {
        showFileChooser();
    }
    if(v == buttonUpload){
        uploadImage();
    }
}
}
```

2.RequestHandler.java

```
public class RequestHandler {

public String sendGetRequest(String uri) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(uri);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

        String result;

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        while((result = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
            sb.append(result);
        }

        return sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}

public String sendPostRequest(String requestURL,
                              HashMap<String, String> postDataParams) {

    URL url;
    String response = "";
    try {
        url = new URL(requestURL);

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);


        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
        writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));

        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        os.close();
        int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

        if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            response = br.readLine();
        } else {
            response = "Error Registering";
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return response;
}

private String getPostDataString(HashMap<String, String> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
        if (first)
            first = false;
        else
            result.append("&");

        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
        result.append("=");
        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
    }

    return result.toString();
}
}
```

3.upload.php

```
<?php

 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

 $username = $_POST['username'];
 $image = $_POST['image'];

 require_once('dbConnect.php');

 $sql = "INSERT INTO android_image (image) VALUES (?) WHERE username  ='".$username."'";

 $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con,$sql);

 mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"s",$image);
 mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

 $check = mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt);

     if($check == 1)
     {
     echo "Image Uploaded Successfully";
     }
     else
     {
     echo "Error Uploading Image";
     }
     mysqli_close($con);
 }
 else
 {
 echo "Error";
 }
```

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "the image will be uploaded to that specific id". Is the id part of the url? I dont get it.

Comment: so database table will consist of id and image column. then i will input the id in editText and the image will be input to that specific id which i enter.

Comment: what i wishes to do is something like this : String url = GetProfile.DATA_URL+receiveSpEmail.toString().trim();

Comment: actually im using email not id to check where i wishes to put. i have no idea why i put id in the question. really sorry about that

Comment: Send the `id` in your request along with the image.

Comment: @PrerakSola so do i need to put it here? protected String doInBackground(Bitmap...params)  --- String result = rh.sendPostRequest(UPLOAD_URL,data); do i just add UPLOAD_URL+email?

Comment: You need to know server side specifics. Actually you just send data to server, and BE is the part where the stuffs go on. Talk with BE devs how to send the email of the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add it in your Hashmap like below:

```
HashMap<String,String> data = new HashMap<>();
data.put(UPLOAD_KEY, uploadImage);
data.put("id", [your value for the id]);
```

And on the server side, you can get the value for the `id` using `$_POST["id"]` if you are using PHP.

Comment: am i doing it right?  private void uploadImage(){ final String username = editTextId.getText().toString(); and then in HashMap, data.put("username", username ); and in PHP $username = $_POST['username']; WHERE username ='".$username."'

Comment: Yeah sounds good. Just test it and you'll know if its good or not.

Comment: sorry to bother you again but it didnt work. after i click upload image it display toast </br> and didnt update on database either

Comment: What do you get in `result` variable in your `doInBackground()`? Print that variable to the logcat. There might be some errors on the PHP side. And how do you access your image on PHP side?

Comment: ive edited the question to include php file. and about the logcat im not too familiar with android studio so i just put "result" in the search box next to "verbose" drop down. is it correct?

Comment: No. Add `Log.i("result", result);` above the `return result;` line.

Comment: 3432-3471/com.example.user.uploadimageblob I/result﹕ <br /> so this is what i get.

Comment: That's weird. Was your code working before? Can you confirm that there is no issue in your PHP side?

Comment: yes, no problem uploading image to the database. sorry for the late reply